# How to get the parent node of d3.select

Tags: javascript, d3.js

again, I have no idea how to get the needed information.

For the following SVG-Objects, I need to get the group tag:

```
<g id="a39" style="touch-action: none; -webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);" transform="translate(0 0)">
  <line class="hotwater graphic selectedGraphic" x1="400" y1="-70" x2="670" y2="-70" id="g39"></line>
  <line class="hotwater graphic selectedGraphic" x1="400" y1="-50" x2="670" y2="-50" id="g39"></line>
</g>

<g id="a40" style="touch-action: none; -webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);">
  <polyline class="warmbrinewater graphic selectedGraphic" fill="none" points="300,-20,240,-160,50,-90,300,-20" id="g40"></polyline>
</g>
```

My selector is the class `selectedGraphic`. I need to assign a translation to the encapsulation group-tag. But I have no idea how to get the parent Nodes...

```
d3.selectAll('.selectedGraphic').**FIRSTELEMENTSPARENT**.attr("transform", "translate(" + xPos + " " + yPos + ")");
```

Any ideas?

Thanks, Carsten

UPDATE:

Actually I solve it this way:

```
var sel = document.getElementsByClassName('selectedGraphic');
for (var i = 0; i < sel.length; i++) {
    sel[i].parentNode.setAttribute('transform', "translate(" + xPos + " " + yPos + ")");
}
```

But I'd appreciate to solve it, using d3.

Answer (score 0):

you can select the parent using `node().parentNode` like this:

```
d3.selectAll('.selectedGraphic').node().parentNode;
```

This will return the parent node, but not sure if you have to do another `d3.select()` on it.

Comment: Yes, that was my question. 
With `d3.selectAll('.selectedGraphic).node().parentNode`I only get an html-string.
How do I do another select on that?

Comment: `d3.select(d3.selectAll('.selectedGraphic).node().parentNode)` something like this, but its ugly, a more readable way is to assign the first to a variable and then use it in the second `d3.select`

Comment: Yes ugly is the rigth word for this :D

But d3.select would return only one node, wouldn't it?

Comment: @Telefisch yes, I believe you have to loop through the nodes and then select the parent each of the nodes here, or why not just basically do a select on the parent through class attribute? is there something preventing this? just add a class on parents and do a select on them directly, this is a better way I guess.

Comment: Assigning a class to the parent would break the whole selection, and saving to database concept but... yes, if there is no better way :-(  I thought d3js is much more flexible.

Comment: Ma'moun othman, solved it simple, as you meant.  

My click-events are always fired on the first group, so I could add a new class for moving. Works fine.

Comment: Add your answer and accept it to get more reputation ;)

Answer (score 0):

So, as mentioned, I will answer my question by myself.

Because I had no solution for my problem, I solved it another was. I needed access to the encapsulation g-tag, because I wanted to move all svg-objects by assigning a transform to the group. My selection based on the class "selectedGraphic", that I assigned to the lines (in this case), with click-event.

Now I simply added a class "movable" to the g-tag, when clicking the elements (they catch the event). This class is now selected for movement.

For future needs, I added a simple recursive function, that gets the very first parent of every child, inside an svg-area:

```
function getFirstParent(svgChild) {
  //svgChild ist ein DOM-Object, kein d3-Object
  if (svgChild.parentNode.tagName == 'svg')
    return svgChild;
  else
    return getFirstParent(svgChild.parentNode);
}
```

The result is a simple DOM-Object, so I still have no working solution to solve this with d3.

Perhaps this helps someone else  :)

Comment: This whole looks like an XY-problem to me. Your approach looks somewhat akward. Please describe what you are trying to do, not how you are trying to fix your—probably screwed up—solution. Where is this happening? Is it an event handler?

Comment: I tried to get access to the parent svg-element of some selected svg children.

Comment: Yeah, I already got that, but the question is still missing some context. It would benefit very much from setting up a [mcve] or at least the relevant parts of your code where you are trying to select the parent element. I am sure there will be a surprisingly simple answer doing it in D3.

Answer (score 0):

If you're still interested in a d3 solution, you can do it like so:

```
d3.selectAll(".selectedGraphic").each(function () {
  d3.select(this.parentElement).attr("transform", `translate(${xPos},${yPos})`);
});
```

Same in TypeScript:

```
d3.selectAll<Element, null>(".selectedGraphic").each(function () {
  d3.select(this.parentElement).attr("transform", `translate(${xPos},${yPos})`);
});
```